# Does 'SVN' has the mechanism to squash commits like git has?

Tags: git, svn, commit, squash

I found out that Git has the mechanism to squash commits.

The link below demonstrates very well how to achieve it.
(http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)

but we are using an SVN system (especially tortoise svn).

Does 'SVN' has the same mechanism to squash commits as git has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svn has no possibility to rewrite the history, so once changes are pushed on the server, no you can't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said, I have also found that svn does not provide chance to modify any commit history. but I get known that svn give me chance to modify commit messages. I am only able to modify commit messages.

Comment: To clarify, while you can modify a commit message in svn, what you're really doing is adding a new version of a commit message. The history remains intact. This is important for safety and compliance - you can't check in an empty file and then squash all prior commits, destroying code.